# Could Hawkeye tell us the probability of runs and wickets from a given ball?

Tags: cricket, statistics, video-review

Suppose the information recorded by Hawkeye was combined with information about the number of runs scored (including boundaries, but excluding overthrows) and wickets taken in each delivery.

An enterprising new bowler might want to know the types of delivery that reduce the runs and increase the likelihood of wickets, or an experienced first-class bowler may want to know what types are affecting their productivity.

Could a large enough amount of Hawkeye data be used to calculate expected runs and expected wickets for each delivery?

Comment: *[This question originally asked](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102995/sports-analytics/103026#103026) by **[Steve](https://stackexchange.com/users/9221695/steve)** on proposal Sports Analytics, which recently closed.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes, here is some work on calculating [expected runs](https://cricketsavant.wordpress.com/2016/12/26/introducing-expected-runs/) and [expected wickets](https://cricketsavant.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/measuring-expected-wickets/).

Comment: Link-only answers are prone to linkrot and the Princess-Castle problem. Please expand on the information in the links and provide your own commentary/explanation where appropriate.